# Loop Through a Grouped Column in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, loops, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to compare every combination of phrases within a grouping to match and score them. I'm getting hung up on the looping through the groups:

```
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz as fz
import itertools

data = [[1,'ab'],[1,'bc'],[1,'de'],[2,'gh'],[2,'hi'],[2,'jk'],[3,'kl'],[3,'lm'],[3,'yz']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Ids','DESCR'])

def iterated(df):
    for a, b in itertools.product(df['DESCR'],df['DESCR']):
        try:
            print(a, b, fz.partial_ratio(a, b), fz.token_set_ratio(a,b))
        except:
            pass
    return result

df.groupby('Ids').apply(iterated(df))
```

The above is comparing each DESCR against everything in the whole list, rather than restricting it to each grouping. I'm getting:

```
ab ab 100 100
ab bc 50 50
ab de 0 0
ab gh 0 0
ab hi 0 0
ab jk 0 0
ab kl 0 0
ab lm 0 0
ab yz 0 0
bc ab 67 50
bc bc 100 100
bc de 0 0
bc gh 0 0
bc hi 0 0
bc jk 0 0
bc kl 0 0
bc lm 0 0
bc yz 0 0
...
```

But it should be:

```
ab bc 50 50
ab de 0 0
bc de 0 0
gh hi 50 50
gh jk 0 0
hi jk 50 50
...
```

Thank you.

Comment: I've updated the sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is you aren't handling the groups correctly.  You are grouping and then applying your function based on the DESCR results in the *entire* df with your command `.apply(iterated(df))`.  Also, I think you want to use `combinations` instead of `product`.

You may need to break it apart and handle the groups individually.  Consider:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
data = [[1,'ab'],[1,'bc'],[1,'de'],[2,'gh'],[2,'hi'],[2,'jk'],[3,'kl'],[3,'lm'],[3,'yz']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Ids','DESCR'])

def show_combos(df):  #replace with your function...
    combos = itertools.combinations(df.DESCR, 2)
    for c in combos:
        print(c)

groups = df.groupby('Ids')

#iterate through the groups, which are mini-data frames
for name, group in groups:
    print('group name: {}'.format(name))
    show_combos(group)
    print()
```

Which yields the groups you wanted:

```
group name: 1
('ab', 'bc')
('ab', 'de')
('bc', 'de')

group name: 2
('gh', 'hi')
('gh', 'jk')
('hi', 'jk')

group name: 3
('kl', 'lm')
('kl', 'yz')
('lm', 'yz')
```

Comment: Thank you very much - you're right about me applying the loop back to the whole frame - just couldn't figure how to apply it to the specific group only.